# Function to stop all future javascript loading on that page

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a function in vanilla javascript or jQuery which would not allow any further javascript to run on that page? Ideally it wouldn't ruin any affects of previously loaded JS, but would stop any future code being executed.

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us why, we can think of a way to assist with what you are actually trying to do? For example `document.write('</script>')` might do the trick

Comment: I don't really see how the context is relevant, but I want to know if there is a way to improve the efficiency of a number of sites which try to load further content through JS whilst streaming videos.

Comment: There are more use cases for this, however. Hence me asking the question in a more generic way.

Comment: You can use a proxy and strip out unwanted ad code for example. The reason I asked is that often such generic questions are X/Y problems

Comment: What scripts do you expect to be prevented from execution? Your own scripts (accidentally included by your server - however), scripts injected via XSS vulnerabilities, userscripts, browser extensions, scripts running in developer tools? Should code already being executing (event handlers, websockets, `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()`, ...) also stopped? Do you want to kind of "demand" for script blockers like NoScript to act on your page?